# Grails searchable plugin and Query Builder

Tags: search, grails, plugins

I;'m having a problem with the searchable plugin (0.6.4).

My domain classes that are involved in my problem are these ones:

```
class AdminArea {
    static searchable = true
    String name     
    static belongsTo = [country:Country]    

}
```

and (I have deleted non important fields):

```
class POI{
    static searchable = {
        adminArea component: true
    }
    String name
    AdminArea adminArea 
}
```

What I have in my app is a normal searchbar and a select that lets me choose the admin area so I can narrow the results a bit. To accomplish this, I have been trying to do the following:

In my searchable Controller, where I build the query:

```
def results = POI.search({

                must{
                    queryString(searchTerm)
                    must(term('adminArea', params.adminArea))                                   
                    }
                })
```

I have tried with many combinations, like adminArea.id, adminArea.name, changing the values of the select in the gsp to ids, names.... but nothing seems to do the trick, I cant notice what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way through rhis.. the queries in searchable are not good at all, so I have to came around and solve it like this:

```
def results = POI.search{               
            must(queryString(searchTerm + " AND adminArea.id: " + params.adminArea))
        }
```